Angular Getting Started project failing at "Pass data to a child component"
I've tried to follow the "Getting Started" sample project from Angular: https://angular.io/start#getting-started-with-angular
In the section Pass data to a child component I fail in step 7. It reads "The generator automatically added the ProductAlertsComponent to the AppModule to make it available to other components in the application." In my project on StackBlitz however this is not the case. The changes that are shown in the code snippets do not exist in my project.
When I add the changes manually I get an error after adding
import { ProductAlertsComponent } from './product-alerts/product-alerts.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopBarComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    ProductAlertsComponent,
  ],

to src/app/app.module.ts
The error in the terminal reads
Application bundle generation failed. [0.193 secon
✘ [ERROR] TS-996008: Component ProductAlertsComponent is standalone, and cannot be declared in an NgModule. Did you mean to import it instead? [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.module.ts:23:4:
      23 │     ProductAlertsComponent

However, I also added it to the import section as shown above.
I am completely new to Angular (hence the tutorial) but this is really frustrating.

With standalone components, you don't need a module declaring them. You can just import the standalone component (in modules or other components).
